# How do different text/wysiwyg editors receive and render COPY/PASTE data?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, browser, wysiwyg

I notice different wysiwyg editors renders copied/paste content differently. For example:

- [bootstrap-wysiwyg](https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) preserves all the html styling of the content I copy/paste.
- http://blitzen.github.io/ does not preserve html styling
- My mac's TextEditor preserve *some* styling but not images.

My questions are:

- What actually gets copied when you copy a paragraph with text and images? What decides what data gets copied? The browser and OS?
- When you paste into an editor, does the editor have all the data you've copied and decide what to render and what to throw away?